# @Restcontroller advice and @ExceptionHandler not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

For my spring-boot project, I am creating one web app and trying to handle all exceptions except constraint violation exception with `BAD_REQUEST` but that is not working as intended and original exception is rethrowing to the user.
below is my controller:

```
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/jobs")
public class JobController {

    JobService jobService;

    @PostMapping("/add")
    public Job addJobListing(@Valid @RequestBody Job job){
        return jobService.addJobPosting(job);
    }

    @GetMapping("/all")
    public List<Job> getAllJobs(@RequestParam(value = "number", defaultValue = "0") Integer pageNumber,
                                @RequestParam( value = "size", defaultValue = "10") Integer pageSize,
                                @RequestParam(value = "title", required = false) String title,
                                @RequestParam(value = "minSalary", required = false) @Min(0) Integer minSalary,
                                @RequestParam(value = "maxSalary", required = false ) @Max(99999) Integer maxSalary,
                                @RequestParam(value = "contains", required = false ) String description,
                                @RequestParam(value = "skills", required = false) String preferredSkills ){
        return jobService.retrieveAllJobs(pageNumber, pageSize, title, minSalary, maxSalary, description, preferredSkills);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Job getJobById(@PathVariable("id") String id) throws Exception {
        return jobService.retrieveJobById(id);
    }
}
```

below is my advice class:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
@Slf4j
public class CustomExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value= ConstraintViolationException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> constraintViolationHandler(ConstraintViolationException ex, HttpResponse response){
      Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
      map.put("message", ex.getMessage());
      
      log.error("received error:"+ex.getMessage());
      return new ResponseEntity<>(ex.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(value= Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> normlExceptionHandler(Exception ex, HttpResponse response){
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("message", ex.getMessage());
        
        log.error("received error:"+ex.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(ex.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to use @ExceptionHandler(TransactionSystemException.class) for handling ConstraintViolationException

Comment: But it should be propogate to 2nd method right?

Comment: Im not sure that I understand you. ConstraintViolationException should be catched with @ExceptionHandler(TransactionSystemException.class)

Comment: I am facing issue with normal exception as well

Comment: If none of the exceptions are handled by the CustomExceptionHandler, did you check if the component is scanned by spring boot?

Comment: yes, while receiving the exception I am getting the below error:
`CustomExceptionHandler.constraintViolationHandler(com.exception.InvalidJobException,java.net.http.HttpResponse): No suitable resolver`